# Converting bytes to file in Django / Python

Tags: python, django, bytesio

In my Django app, I have a PDF in bytes:

```
print(myPDF)
> b'%PDF-1.3\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Pages\n/Count 2....
```

I want to save it in my database:

```
obj.document = myPDF
obj.save()
```

However I keep getting an `'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'` error on save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a built-in Django function, [ContentFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/).

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
...

obj.document = ContentFile(myPDF, '........pdf')
obj.save()
```